# Kafka monitoring using Burrow

Tags: apache-kafka, lag, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

When using Burrow to monitor Kafka

1) What do the Burrow start and end offset for a given consumer group in a topic partition mean? I could not find any documentation on this.

What is the matching Kafka terminology? Kafka terminology : Last Committed offset, Current Offset, Highwater mark Offset, Log End Offset. What does Burrow start and end offset map to? Is it the Kafka Current Offset and kafka Highwater mark offset?

For eg.

`http://localhost:8000/v2/kafka/local/consumer/MyGroup-1-4/lag`

```json
{
   "error":false,
   "message":"consumer group status returned",
   "status":{
      "cluster":"local",
      "group":"MyGroup-1-4",
      "status":"ERR",
      "complete":false,
      "partitions":[
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":1,
            "status":"OK",
            "start":{
               "offset":28,
               "timestamp":1468769616468,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":34,
               "timestamp":1468805045000,
               "lag":0
            }
         },
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":3,
            "status":"STOP",
            "start":{
               "offset":32,
               "timestamp":1468803763000,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":32,
               "timestamp":1468804303000,
               "lag":0
            }
         },
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":4,
            "status":"OK",
            "start":{
               "offset":32,
               "timestamp":1468804003000,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":33,
               "timestamp":1468804783000,
               "lag":0
            }
         },
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":5,
            "status":"STOP",
            "start":{
               "offset":32,
               "timestamp":1468803763000,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":32,
               "timestamp":1468804303000,
               "lag":0
            }
         },
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":6,
            "status":"OK",
            "start":{
               "offset":33,
               "timestamp":1468804423000,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":34,
               "timestamp":1468805045000,
               "lag":0
            }
         },
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":7,
            "status":"OK",
            "start":{
               "offset":27,
               "timestamp":1468769387995,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":33,
               "timestamp":1468804783000,
               "lag":0
            }
         },
         {
            "topic":"MyTopicTest-1",
            "partition":9,
            "status":"OK",
            "start":{
               "offset":27,
               "timestamp":1468769433946,
               "lag":0
            },
            "end":{
               "offset":33,
               "timestamp":1468804783000,
               "lag":0
            }
         }
      ],
      "partition_count":10,
      "maxlag":null,
      "totallag":0
   },
   "request":{
      "url":"/v2/kafka/local/consumer/MyGroup-1-4/lag",
      "host":"****",
      "cluster":"local",
      "group":"MyGroup-1-4",
      "topic":""
   }
}
```

2) Some status are marked as STOPPED. Burrow rule for marking status as STOPPED is:
*If the difference between the time now and the time of the most recent offset is greater than the difference between the most recent offset and the oldest offset in the window, the consumer is in an ERROR state and the partition is marked as STOPPED. However, if the consumer offset and the current broker offset for the partition are equal, the partition is not considered to be in error.*

What is "time now"? Is it the time at which the lag request was sent to Burrow

Answer (score 3):

**1) What do the Burrow start and end offset for a given consumer group in a topic partition mean? I could not find any documentation on this.**
These two offsets means the start and end offsets(consumer committed offsets) in **logcheck evaluation window**. The default window will store 10 offsets, and used to evaluate consumer lag.
please refer to below diagram and link.
[Burrow: Kafka Consumer Monitoring Reinvented](https://engineering.linkedin.com/apache-kafka/burrow-kafka-consumer-monitoring-reinvented)
[image]

**2, What is "time now"? Is it the time at which the lag request was sent to Burrow?**
The "time now" means current "lagcheck interval". you can get more detailed example in [Example 5](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/wiki/Consumer-Lag-Evaluation-Rules).

> The difference in time between the first offset stored and the last
>   offset stored is 540 seconds, and the difference in time between now
>   and the last offset stored is 660 seconds. The consumer has stopped
>   committing offsets, which means it has failed or has been stopped.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. If the "start"  offset is  "__consumer_offsets topic"  and "end" offset is "Broker HEAD offset" for each partition then why not Burrow calls them as what they are and not  introduce a new "start" and "end" terminology. Also why print the "start" and "end" offsets at all? Just print the difference and call it "lag" to keep it clear.

Comment: Or am I missing something?

Comment: The start and end means the consumer committed offsets in lag evaluation window. The lag is calculated as difference between the HEAD offset of the broker and the consumer's offset. Default logcheck window will have 10 offsets. actually we decide the consumer status by single "status":"ERR" indicator.  start and end offset information help to get the lag details.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. So for the default logcheck window, the start is the 1st offset in the window and the end is the 10th offset in the window. Isn't HEAD offset the end of the log in the current partition and this offset may not have been replicated yet. Should'nt one calculate lag from the offset that has been replicated to all the replicas and the current commited offset in the window.